# Regex with multiple patterns only returning results for one pattern

Tags: python, regex

I can't imagine this is a difficult question, but I'm having a hard time finding a solution to this online.

I'm attempting to find the price in a string, sometimes the euro sign is present, sometimes it is not, so I search for both cases in my regex. However, in the case shown below my regex only ever returns '€6' and not '6'. It was my though that the order of multiple patterns in the regex mattered, so having (?<=for €)(.*) first should cause this code to return '6', but it does not.

It also doesn't seem to pick up just '6' if I use re.findall, the only case where this code works is if I remove the option (?<=for )(.*) entirely from the regex.

Any help in better understanding this problem is greatly appreciated!

```
import re

deal = '2 for €6'
price = (re.search(r"(?<=for €)(.*)|(?<=for )(.*)", deal.lower()))[0]

print(price)
```

Comment: Sorry I had just deleted my reply as I've figured out what I was looking for thanks to your solution. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asserting that from the current position, to the left must by either `for €` or `for`

So stepping 1 position to the right each time, the assertion `(?<=for`  becomes true before `(?<=for €` becomes true and you will match (capture) €6 due to the `(.*)`

Note that this match will not change if you switch the order of the alternatives, as both alternatives will be tested in this case.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JOsJEu/1)

Or if you want both values in 2 capture groups (**note** that `.*` matches the whole line, and `\d+` matches 1+ digits):

```
for (?=(€(\d+)))
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2Uwqli/1)